# Выделение памяти под теги

Tags: html, оптимизация, производительность

Имеет ли большое значение то, какие теги использовать для представления одного и того же вида информации на странице, допустим, параграфа статьи? Выделяет ли движок браузера разное количество памяти под, допустим, теги `<div>` и `<p>`, и сильно ли это может сказаться на производительности при необходимости отобразить страницу с большим количеством узлов на мобильном устройстве?

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае да, т.к. разные элементы имеют разный набор свойств, и разные наборы событий, что в свою очередь сказывается на количестве необходимой памяти и обработке. С другой стороны это всё сильно зависит от внутренней реализации браузера.

Поэтому в конкретном случае вам поможет только фактическое тестирование, делаете документ с 10k элементов одного типа, другого и сравниваете скорость и потребление памяти в разных браузерах.

Я бы предположил что влияние это в общем случае ничтожно. Но это всего лишь предположение.

Answer (score 0):

Решил провести тест. Создал Html страницу с 10000 `div` в которые вставил `Lorem ipsum...` в среднем она загружается за `1.33` такая же страница, но 10000 `p` в среднем загружается за `1.32`.
[image: 1000 DIV]
[image: 1000 P]

Так что решайте сами, что использовать.

Comment: Я имел ввиду выделение оперативной памяти. В случае с объёмом файла разница, конечно, будет незначительной.